# HTML displays item in the last row of column

Tags: html, django-templates

I am creating a table in Django templates like this:

HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>P.Info</th>
        <th>Std Qty</th>
        <th>Components per kit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.product_name }}</td>
          {% for i in quantities %}
            {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
                <td id="q{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ i }}</td>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
          <td>{{ components_perkit }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and this creates:

[image]

Why is components per kit displayed in the last row and not in the middle of the column?
How can I change this such that it shows "140" in the middle of the column?

Comment: Due to the if statement, the cell is only being output for the last row (assuming that the condition is falsy for all other rows, resulting in them having only 3 cells instead of 4). As for a solution, I'll leave that to someone who actually uses django-templates, which is not me. ;-)

Comment: Seems to me you need a rowspan

Answer (score 0):

You need a `rowspan="{{products.length}}"` or whatever length is in django

```css
td { border: 1px solid black }
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>P.Info</th>
        <th>Std Qty</th>
        <th>Components per kit</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td id="q1">q1</td>
        <td rowspan="4">{{ components_perkit }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td id="q2">q2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td id="q3">q3</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```